# Sendmail command to send a file as an email body as well as attachment

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sendmail

I want to send an email using sendmail command in `bash`. The email should get it's body by reading `Input_file_HTML` and it should send same input file as an attachment too. To do so I have tried the following.

```
sendmail_touser() {
cat - ${Input_file_HTML} << EOF | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
From: ${MAILFROM}
To: ${MAILTO}
Subject: $1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
cat ${Input_file_HTML}
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename: ${Input_file_HTML}
EOF
}
```

The above command is giving an email with only the attachment of `Input_file_HTML` and it is not writing it in the body of email. Could you please help/guide me on same? I am using outlook as the email client. I have even removed the `cat` command in above command, but it also is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mutt` instead?

```
echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a "/path/to/file.to.attach" -s "subject of message" -- recipient@domain.com
```

To install `mutt` on Debian systems:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mutt
```

**EDIT** Try this if you can only use `sendmail`:

```
sendmail_attachment() {
    FROM="$1"
    TO="$2"
    SUBJECT="$3"
    FILEPATH="$4"
    CONTENTTYPE="$5"

    (
    echo "From: $FROM"
    echo "To: $TO"
    echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
    echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
    echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"'
    echo ""
    echo "--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"
    echo "Content-Type: text/html"
    echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
    echo "<p>Message contents</p>"
    echo ""
    echo "--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"
    echo "Content-Type: $CONTENTTYPE"
    echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$(basename $FILEPATH)"
    echo ""
    cat $FILEPATH
    echo ""
    ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
}
```

Use like this:

```
sendmail_attachment "to@example.com" "from@example.com" "Email subject" "/home/user/file.txt" "text/plain"
```

Comment: Hello Nick,
Thank you for your reply. I am not a root and I don't have mutt command. Could you please guide me here, will be grateful to you.

Comment: Could you ask the sysadmin to install it? This is a very simple way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @RavinderSingh The update might work for you.

Comment: Hello Nick: It is giving me following error.
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
No, I believe they wouldn't install mutt.

Comment: @RavinderSingh See update.